# Creating a Sortable List using Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I need a bit of help making my list sortable using jquery ui :)

HTML:

```
<ul id="listSort">
<li class="list-group-item"> You can remove items by double clicking.</li>
<li class="list-group-item"> Add More!</li>
```

JavaScript:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#listSort").sortable();
});
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/   view source there and you will find what you looking for :)

Comment: What's your question?